# The project cannot be built until its prerequisite PokerGameEngine is built. Cleaning and building all projects is recommended

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, build

The project cannot be built until its prerequisite PokerGameEngine is built. Cleaning and building all projects is recommended  PokerExtension      Unknown Java Problem

in eclipse

it shows red cross mark on project.

i have done build automatically and clean all  in eclipse for all projects

but it shows red cross

Comment: there seems to be a dependency issue. try to first compile PokerGameEngine without any errors. you cannot build your dependent project until you resolve these errors first

Comment: I would guess that PokerExtension is the project that is red and it has Maven dependancy on PokerGameEngine project, which you don't have in Eclipse or you need to Maven install.

Comment: eclipse is so unreliable ... not only does it not work, the diagnostics are misleading

Answer (score 3):

For Eclipse you can find the rebuild option in the top menu under Project > Clean and then select the project you want to clean up... that's all.

Eclipse Clean projects selected below
[image]

This will build your project and create a new bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem with Eclipse when I was developing on projects that depends on each others. I had got two projects A and B. A depends on B and B depends on A. That may cause problems. If it's the case, right click on the project A, then click 'Build Project'. Then, the same thing for project B.

I solved my problem doing theses steps.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround in eclipse bug [536592](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536592),

> to disable "Java/Compiler/Building/Build path problems/Abort build
> when build path errors occur".
>
> When doing this the "clean build" will take a long time but will finish
> successfully (after showing thousands of errors due to the mentioned
> random build path). Its the brute force building method ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you mess around with project and classpath files outside of eclipse (in my case managing the git repo with checkouts and merges) and then close the eclipse with errors during its exit.

Each time this happens, next time I open eclipse and make a Project->Clean->AllProjects, the build fails with this error for some projects - with the *prerequisite* projects having no errors(!). In order to build successfully, I have to manually refresh (right click on project->Refresh) the prerequisite projects.

The solution to this is just to exit once the build succeeds, let the eclipse shut down normally and next time I lunch it, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following points to resolve the error:

- There is an errors tab. It prompts you the problem with the project.
- Make sure that none of the prerequisit projects has an x mark next to it. In your case PokerGameEngine. If so rebuild it and make sure that all errors are resolved.
- If you have check style issues, resolve them.
- Navigate into the project till you reach the file that has the x mark too, and resolve it.

X mark mainly means that some prerequisits are missing or some coding error exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, I think any of the below will help you

- Try clean and build all the projects
- Try refreshing each projects manually
- Try clean and build each projects manually

If all those steps are useless, this might helps you

- Delete all projects in eclipse(while deleting, make sure you unchecked "Delete project content on the Disk") and import your projects from scratch, you maven built already.

My problem got solved by following these steps.

Answer (score -1):

If both projects are mavenised then update PokerGameEngine project. Right click on it -> Maven -> Update Project. or (Alt+F5)

Comment: Update project doesn't update your .m2 with the built artifacts.